# "" in line.map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm checking if there's any "" value in a elements array like this

```
"" in line.map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()
```

and it is returning false, but when i debug it on browser i get this on array

```
line.map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get() = ["1", "2", "4", "", "", "", "", "", "3"]
```

i suppose that this should be returning true right?

i have already tried with `.each` but i can't return it unless i use a global variable with a `return false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) does not check whether an array contains a value (that would be [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)), it enumerates properties on an object. For example:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

for (f in data) {
  console.log('gets the index:', f);
  console.log('gets the value:', data[f]); // <- note the access using f
}
```

Rather, you should be using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you need the element or [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if you just need to check presence:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

console.log('find an element by value:', data.find(it => it === 'c'));
console.log('check if any elements match:', data.some(it => it === 'c'));
```

Comment: great ty
by the way what means it => it ?

Comment: @JoelRodrigues that's the short-hand for a lambda (or fat arrow) function. They're anonymous functions that are typically a single expression, perfect for predicates in `find` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a filter, and checking the length

```
var hasEmpty = line.filter(function(){ return $(this).val().trim() === ""}).length > 0;
```

or a little more ES2015, using `Array.some` on a jQuery collection

```
var hasEmpty = line.toArray().some((el) => $(el).val() === "");
```

Comment: If performance matters (**if**), I would hesitate to use `filter` as a replacement for `some`, since it can't break out early while a `for` loop can. That's also a concern for *very* large arrays. This will work and usually work well, but they're not totally equivalent.

Comment: @ssube - nope, they're not the same, but for a collection of elements it shouldn't matter, unless the OP has millions of elements of course?